# GRUB - Boot second OS on request

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb-drive, boot-repair

Is there any way to use dual boot with GRUB with intelligence? I want to boot the second OS on computer if a special USB-memory is inserted to computer. 
The reason is that the computer is a embedded platform and in field.

Comment: Legacy BIOS or UEFI? Do you have remote access to the console (serial or remote KVM)?

Comment: Copy your preferred menuentry from your USB's grub.cfg to /etc/grub.d/40_custom on your internal drive. Boot computer and run update-grub.

Comment: Is second OS on computer or the USB stick?

Comment: Legacy BIOS and no access to the console.

Comment: Both OS is on the hard drive.